# PHP displaying content of shortcode outside of shortcode tags

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I'm trying to output

```
[embedyt]http://www.youtube.com/embed?layout=gallery&listType=playlist&list=*some-playlist*[/embedyt]
```

By using a combination of Advanced Custom Fields and a YouTube plugin in Wordpress.

My code is:

```
        <?php 
echo do_shortcode('[[embedyt]' . the_field('youtube-playlist') . '[/embedyt]]');
        ?>
```

where the [emedyt] tags are from Embed YouTube and the_field('youtube-playlist') is from Advanced Custom Fields.

Unfortunately what gets output is

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed?layout=gallery&listType=playlist&list=*some-test-playlist*[embedyt][/embedyt]
```

I don't understand where I am going wrong with my PHP, I have different variations, like using variables and different types of concatenating but I am obviously missing something.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can the Embed YouTube actually contain playlists? It might something as banale as that, throwing an error you cannot see. Have you tried just using a single link to a youtube-video? Does it work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `the_field` function which actually prints the value of custom field but you actually need to pass the value to `do_shortcode` function instead of displaying it.

You've to use `get_field` function instead. Try updating your code to following

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[[embedyt]' . get_field('youtube-playlist') . '[/embedyt]]'); ?>
```

Comment: You were right. The only thing I would add is I realized I didn't need the extra brackets around the shortcode so my code ended up looking like this: 
   <?php 
    echo do_shortcode('[embedyt]' . get_field('youtube-playlist') . '[/embedyt]'); 
   ?>